# How to register Windows Phone 8?? What is Windows Phone IP Over USB Transport(IpOverUsbSvc)?

Tags: registration, windows-phone-8

I have got a Windows Phone 8 and am trying to register it with the developer account.

I am using the tool "Windows Phone Developer Registration" that comes with Visual studio 2012.

But when I try to register, I get a message

"For Windows Phone8 phones make sure that the Windows Phone IP Over USB Transport(IpOverUsbSvc) service is running"

Would like to know what is this service and how to run it.. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: :( Having the same problem - I've got an active Sim in my phone and the service in question is running.

Comment: @aaronsnoswell Do you have the [$99 account](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/join) at the dev center?

Comment: No I didn't - solved it now though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an FYI, you will need a Active MICRO SIM as well to register the Windows Phone 8.
I faced many errors and was able to do it successfully when I inserted an Active Mirco Sim

Comment: What's an Active Micro Sim?

Comment: @nkchandra give me the correct answer. The IpOverUsbSvc was stopped.

Comment: This answer may be incorrect, but this little piece of information saved me after several hours of struggle. This is so absurd, we never use SIM cards in our android/iOS development devices.

Comment: This is correct answer, I believed the IpOverUsbSvc might be a problem as well. But in my case, I successful register for the developer when I put my SIM in.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the phone needs a *working internet connection*, either via an active data enabled SIM, or via WiFi (that doesn't require exotic proxy configuration)

Answer (score 29):

Go to search in Windows 8 and type "service" under settings, you will find "view Local services" and select it. It opens the services window.

Alternately, Open Control Panel and select "Administative Tools" and you will find "Services" icon in it. Double clicking it also opens the Services window.

After performing one of the above, Find the service with the name "Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc)" and right click on it and Start/Restart the service.

Comment: If its already running try and restart the service, worked for me

Comment: this does not work on my nokia 925, any other solution?

Comment: Hay buddy! its awesome ... it worked fine. Thanks. +1

Comment: Contributing to this -- This does not always work. I'm working on a Lumia 1520 on a Win10 VM. I made an app on Cordova in Win8.1, redoing work on Win10 and when I try restarting or starting the service I get an error that "cannot open ipoverusbsvc on computer '.'"

Answer (score 5):

unplug your device, go to Device Manager, select View → Show hidden devices. You will see your device listed in **Universal Serial Bus devices** and **Portable Devices**. Just uninstall them, plug device again, and done :)

Comment: Tried everything from different USB cables, to restarting the IpOverUsbSvc, this was the only thing that worked. (No SIM card inserted!)

Answer (score 0):

To update - you do NOT need an active SIM for developer unlocking. I purchased a cheap Nokia 520 for device testing and it does not have a SIM at all.

I encountered this error registering my phone, and I had to restart the IpOvrUSBSvc service (it was listed as running, but still didn't work), before the registration was complete.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to disable the VPN under Windows Phone 8.1 to be able to register my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Just my 1 cent.

For me the problem was I was trying to register a new device with a restored os from an old one. 
The issue was the name of new device was the same of the old one. When I renamed the device with a new name it registered with no problem.
Alas the error message was misleading.

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently done some kind of system reset (SOFT/HARD) you should check if **DATE** is set correctly.

Wrong date on device was problem in my case, when trying to register device.
Specially if you are unlocking device that is just used for development it is easy to overlook  wrong date.

I believe that answer that is marked as correct, also depends on changing the DATE, because **when you insert active SIM card, phone will update DateTime via mobile network automatically**