# Registering Windows Phone 8.1 as a Developer Device

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to debug a Windows Visual Studio sample project from Microsoft Virtual Academy and am unable to get it to work with my phone. I am able to debug it for Windows (universal app) but for my phone I am not able to run the emulator or run the app on my phone. I want to get it to work on my phone since that is the option that is supposed to work by default.

I tried to register my device but wasn't able to get very far:
[image: Windows Phone Developer Registration]

I have gone through this (Phone 8)[other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737930/how-to-register-windows-phone-8-what-is-windows-phone-ip-over-usb-transportip) and tried every solution listed (restarted, stopped, and started the service AND even disabling the device in the Device Manager) and it still isn't working. Any other tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in the [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/314a50ee-ac0e-4c78-8c8d-c81092fd362b/no-windows-phone-8-detected?forum=wptools). Overall I was able to register my phone after I:

1. Detached my phone.
2. Uninstalled the four devices (all labeled as my phone) under “Universal Serial Bus Devices” from the Device Manager.
3. Removed the key “HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\usbflags\042106610100” manually (number matched as I have a Nokia 920)
4. Reattached the phone

The longer version is copied from the MSDN and pasted below in case anyone else has this issue.

```
1. Open a command prompt and browse to this folder:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Phone Tools\CoreCon\11.0\Bin

Then run IpOverUsbEnum.exe (with the device unlocked!)

2.Expected results:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Phone Tools\CoreCon\11.0\Bi
 n>ipoverusbenum
 Partner:
   Container Id: 6C5585FD-8C32-587B-BBDE-3DB382497937
   Instance: USB\VID_0421&PID_0661&MI_01\6&2C0EBAFF&0&0001
   Name: RM-820|Nokia Lumia 920
   Guid: 00000011-6AE5-9FD1-0000-000000000000
 Partner Services listening at ports:
   Debugger 8888 -> 127.0.0.1:8888
   DeviceReg 27177 -> 127.0.0.1:27077
   Msvsmon 8016 -> 127.0.0.1:8016
   RPCSurrogate00 6610 -> 127.0.0.1:6510
   RPCSurrogate01 6611 -> 127.0.0.1:6511
   RPCSurrogate02 6612 -> 127.0.0.1:6512
   RPCSurrogate03 6613 -> 127.0.0.1:6513
   RPCSurrogate04 6614 -> 127.0.0.1:6514
   RPCSurrogate05 6615 -> 127.0.0.1:6515
   RPCSurrogate06 6616 -> 127.0.0.1:6516
   RPCSurrogate07 6617 -> 127.0.0.1:6517
   RPCSurrogate08 6618 -> 127.0.0.1:6518
   RPCSurrogate09 6619 -> 127.0.0.1:6519
   RPCSurrogate10 6620 -> 127.0.0.1:6520
   WPConManClient2Proxy 6891 -> 127.0.0.1:6791
   WPPingSirep 29819 -> 127.0.0.1:29819
   WPSirep 29917 -> 127.0.0.1:29817 

If the output is as expected, most likely it’s not an IP Over USB issue.

3. If it reports RPC Server Unavailable, most likely the service is indeed not running on the PC.
 4. If it reports no connected partners found:
 - check the phone is unlocked
 - check it is available in explorer to drag and drop files
 - verify whether the USB device (i.e. the Phone) has been correctly detected and installed. This step is not trivial as it requires looking up the USB device (i.e. the phone) in the registry.

The following example is based on inspection in the registry (regedit) of an installed Nokia 920 device. If looking for a different device, the difference will be in the VID (Vendor ID, represented as VID_vvvv) and PID (Product ID, represented as PID_pppp).

1) Inspect the DeviceInterfaceGUID value in the registry key indicated below. If the device failed to install, that value may be missing. Please note this is the interface 1 (MI_01), interface 2 is used by Nokia for something different.

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_0421&PID_0661&MI_01\7&338e4600&1&0001\Device Parameters]
 "ExtPropDescSemaphore"=dword:00000001
 "DeviceInterfaceGUID"="{26fedc4e-6ac3-4241-9e4d-e3d4b2c5c534}"

2) Inspect the usbflags\042106610100 key below. The osvc value is the relevant thing to look for, it won’t start with 01 if the device wasn’t recognized correctly:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\usbflags\042106610100]
 "osvc"=hex:01,42
 "SkipContainerIdQuery"=hex:01,00,00,00

The long number, in this case 042106610100 was derived from the Vendor ID (0421), the Product ID (0661) and the revision number (0100) of the device.
 More USBFLAGS info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj649944(v=vs.85).aspx

The correct workaround, if these values are not correct, is to (1) uninstall the devices under “Universal Serial Bus Devices” from Device Manager, (2) remove the key “HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\usbflags\042106610100” manually (use that number only if it is the Nokia 920), and then attach the phone again.    

Mark Chamberlain Sr. Escalation Engineer | Microsoft Developer Support | Windows Phone 7
```